# Windows 7 deleting files off external HDD

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, external-hard-drive, windows-registry

I have a 500GB external partitioned into two separate halves. One is for storing things like important documents and other things I don't feel safe having on my internal HDD. The other is formatted into FAT32 and contains movies and music to be accessed from my PS3. (I switch the cables manually for now but plan on buying a switch box) But the problem is only on the "media" half of the HDD where movies and music will disappear for no apparent reason. And on rare occurances, will still show up in Windows but not on PS3.

It's the damnest thing and google and duckduckgo haven't really provided much insight other than "REINSTALL WINDOWS 7!"

From what I can tell, it isn't a virus. My antivirus shows everything as all good. As well as the fact that I use Process Monitor to watch what it's doing from time to time and everything is normal.

So that leaves it down to possible registry errors or somehow my PC, my ISP, or the PS3 are detecting them as illegal (They aren't. I paid for them. But my issues with illegal data being falsely detected are a whole different can of worms for now) downloads and deleting them.

I'm thinking of just reformatting the partition, assigning it a new letter, and downloading everything once again. But I don't know if this will help the registry make new entries for a "new" drive and, therefore, leave my stuff alone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the way windows manages files inside that type of filesystem. It happens when the filesystem is not correctly *closed* (like when you disconnect the drive without using the *Remove Safely* dialog - but this is not always the case).

Try "repairing" it using `CHKDSK /F` or the windows dialog. It's almost always that issue.

Good Luck.

Comment: I tried it and cmd listed no problems with it. Defragmenting showed it was 1% defragmented however and I ran repairs for that. It may not bring back the files I've lost but hopefully it'll prevent more from being deleted.

Comment: Just make sure you unmount them properly and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of the file type compatibility on the PS3.

If the PS3 cannot play a file on the drive, it may not display it at all. I have noticed this behavior with DLNA devices, and may be the same on the PS3.

Here are the types of files that can be played on the PS3:
http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/3_15/video/filetypes.html

Paying particular attention to the 'Hints' section:

```
Hints

- Depending on the data type, some files may not be playable or some control 
  panel options may not function during playback.
- Some video files distributed over the Internet have playback restrictions. 
  For details, contact the content provider.
- To play WMV format files, you must go to  (Settings) >  (System Settings) 
  and set [Enable WMA Playback].
- When using a USB adaptor to play video files, you may need to use a USB 
  adaptor (not included) that supports copyright-protection features (to 
  play copyright-protected files).
- When using a USB adaptor to play AVCHD-format video files saved on 
  Memory Stick™ media, use a device that supports Hi-Speed USB (USB 2.0).
- WMV format copyright-protected files cannot be played.
```

Comment: It isn't the file type since the PS3 did display and play them at one point. The issue is that files that once showed up and played perfectly fine get deleted for no reason whatsoever.

Comment: Errrrm ... Well I'm out of ideas then ... But, just in case it helps, here's a picture of a cat sitting on a dog. http://www.spoof99.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/You-has-awesome-crown.jpg